# Is there a way to pass the data of one interface property as "this" to another property?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

I'm trying to wrap my head around generic types in interfaces and passing the data of one interface property to another.

Maybe it's easier to understand with an example:

```js
interface IExample {
    model: () => Record<string, any>
    evaluator: Record<string, () => boolean>
}
```

The use case would be something like this:

```js
const example: IExample = {
    model: () => {
        // The content can be changed by the user
        return {
            k1: true,
            k2: 'some content',
            k3: [1, 2, 3]
        }
    },
    evaluator: {
        testEvaluator: function () {
            /**
             * This is where I would like to have an autocompletion
             * So internally example.model() is called and
             * the return value is passed as `this`-argument
             */
            return this.k1 === true
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the code comment I would like to provide autocompletion
to the user when he writes his code for an evaluator

What i tried so far looks round about like this:

```js
interface IExample<Model extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
    model: () => Data,
    evaluator: <Record<string, (this: Data) => boolean>
}
```

Is this even possible? If so: I'm really grateful for any kind of hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close with your type, the problem is that typescript will not perform any inference on variables. If you set the type in the variable type annotation then that is the final type.

To get the inference behavior you want you need to use a function. Functions can have extra type parameters that the compiler will infer based on the actual parameter type:

```
interface IExample<Model extends Record<string, any>> {
  model: () => Model,
  evaluator: Record<string, (this: Model) => boolean>
}

function createExample<T>(o: IExample<T>) {
  return o;
}

const example = createExample({
  model: () => ({
    k1: true,
    k2: 'some content',
    k3: [1, 2, 3]
  }),
  evaluator: {
    testEvaluator: function () {
      // this is  { k1: boolean; k2: string; k3: number[]; }

      return this.k1 === true
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much, especially for the explanation. Works like charme